# React & Redux app behaves correctly when in debug-mode with a break-point and incorrectly when without the breakpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've got a copy of the reproduce-able bug on https://github.com/mmoalin/reproduceABug
This application takes in a CSV file. This file will produce an objects array inside the application storing it in a redux state property named fileInputData.

This state property is expecting to have data that is sorted by one of the columns in the csv file (proposal_id) and filtered for empty values. The lines of code doing this are in

> src/logic.js

in the function storeInput, lines 6 and 7:

`options.container = options.container.filter(item => item.proposal_id != "" && item.proposal_id != " ");
//options.container = _.uniqWith(options.container, (arrVal, athVal) => { return arrVal.search_term == athVal.search_term });`

If we place a breakpoint there, the line of code is put into effect and csv is converted into an array of objects, the expected actions occur. If that breakpoint is not hit and the application runs without the debug window open, the line of code doesn't go into effect and instead, the state property named fileInputData results to an empty array.

I'm not sure why this is happening.. If anyone has any ideas, i'd be very grateful :D

*edit* The input file is named 'erroring data.csv' and can be found in the repo above

Comment: [the following](https://github.com/mmoalin/reproduceABug/blob/master/src/fileUploader.js#L82) executes before [this](https://github.com/mmoalin/reproduceABug/blob/master/src/fileUploader.js#L51) Maybe you can use promises instead?

Comment: Thank you i'll give it a try

Comment: That's worked :D Thanks again @hmr